# How do I transfer contacts from my PC to my phone, without putting it in Gmail?

Tags: contacts, sync, sony-ericsson-xperia-x10

I have a Sony Ericsson Xperia Neo. I want to copy my outlook contacts to my phone without gmail. This is my first time I bought a Android. It seems great, but one thing I do not like is that I have to sync my whole life with google first, before I can transfer it. The previous software allowed me to copy back and forth between PC and phone,without going onto the internet.
Hopefully it is something I'm doing wrong, because if it is not, I'm changing OS!

Please help

es

Answer (score 1):

AOSP/Stock Android builds allow importing contacts from SIM cards, or VCF files (which are just text files.)

I am unsure the SE Xperia Neo allows you to do this - if so, it's relatively easy to build a VCF file.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [Sony Ericsson PC Companion](http://www.sonyericsson.com/cws/support/mobilephones/downloads/subject/pccompanion/xperiax10us?cc=us&lc=en) suite?  The latest version's Sync Zone should be able to work with Outlook.

There are other packages on the market that can do this for you, but most are paid like for example [CompanionLink](http://www.companionlink.com/android/outlook/) ($49, free 2 week trial) with its Android app [DejaOffice](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.companionlink.clusbsync).

Answer (score 0):

Sony PC Companion really could be better. From your phone, goto contact list them do a back up contacts. It will writes all your contacts to a VCF file on the SD Card. Then you may merge it to whatever application dealing with VCF files.

Answer (score 0):

1. Move your phone contacts list to the root folder of SD card
2. Tap on the People option on your phone and select import contacts from SD card.
3. Choose the list previously uploaded, then all the contacts will be imported.